WebSocket showing closed for Application deployed with Istio Service Mesh and Ingress Gateway
Prerequisite: Helm charts such as istio-base, istio-discovery, istio-ingress-gateway with app version 1.0.0 applied to the namespace before applying the following application.
I have deployed the 'Tornado - Demo Websockets App' from the link below:
https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/samples/websockets
in the AWS Elastic Kubernetes Cluster. I labeled the namespace with 'istio-injection=enabled' and modified the deployment in the app.yaml file by adding the annotation below:
annotations: sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true" 
However, the WebSocket status remains closed when the application is up.
What should be done to make the WebSocket status open?

I tried below mentioned possible solutions on internet, but it didn't work.

Adding below port details for Gateway

  - port:
      number: 8080
      name: websocket
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"


Adding prefix: /ws for VirtualService
websocketUpgrade: true for VirtualService


I see that the istio discovery pod is running with the latest image,
Image:         gcr.io/istio-testing/pilot:latest
Image ID:      gcr.io/istio-testing/pilot@sha256:2a974ef2bd3cdca71dc2cd9b2b463f8441b70e77ecbd9e05f7f5200cd81e3979
and the deployment is running with the below image,
Image:         gcr.io/istio-testing/proxyv2:latest
Image ID:      gcr.io/istio-testing/proxyv2@sha256:8c358d37d33c013fa5dc8b1c331030e19383a8d02b83c90e27d8d47e4209622e
